# org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, Double), (String, Double))] to Dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala/Spark.
Few of groupby operations in Scala resulted into rdd below. Now i am trying to write the below into sql dataframe and save it in hadoop. however while writing this into sql dataframe its converted into the

Sample RDD format:

```
Array[((String, Double), (String, Double))] = Array(((Veterans Affairs Dept of,11669.0),(Veterans Affairs Dept of,101124.0)), ((Office Wisc Public Defender,40728.0),(Office Wisc Public Defender,40728.0)))
```

direct using .toDF gives

```
 |                  _1|                  _2|
 +--------------------+--------------------+
 |[Veterans Affairs...|[Veterans Affairs...|
 |[Office Wisc Publ...|[Office Wisc Publ...| 
 |[Health Services,...|[Health Services,...|
```

what can i do to get the above in format shown below:

```
|                  _1|                  _2|_3|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|[Veterans Affairs...|11669.0|101124|
|[Office Wisc Publ...|40728|40728|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `RDD` of `((String, Double), (String, Double))` and you want to convert into `RDD` of `(String, Double, Double)`, if `row._1._1` String equals `row._2._1` String.

```
val input: Array[((String, Double), (String, Double))] =
    Array((("Veterans Affairs Dept of", 11669.0), ("Veterans Affairs Dept of", 101124.0)),
      (("Office Wisc Public Defender", 40728.0), ("Office Wisc Public Defender", 40728.0)))
```

input `RDD[((String, Double), (String, Double))]`

```
val myRDD: RDD[((String, Double), (String, Double))] = sc.parallelize(input)
```

convert into `RDD[(String, Double, Double)]` using `flatMap`.

```
val resultRDD: RDD[(String, Double, Double)] =
    myRDD.flatMap(row => row._1._1 match {
      case firstString if firstString == row._2._1 =>
        Some((firstString, row._1._2, row._2._2))
      case _ => None
    })
```

covert RDD into Data Frame.

```
resultRDD.toDF().show()
```

Result:

```
+--------------------+-------+--------+
|                  _1|     _2|      _3|
+--------------------+-------+--------+
|Veterans Affairs ...|11669.0|101124.0|
|Office Wisc Publi...|40728.0| 40728.0|
+--------------------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used groupBy operations then I will assume that both strings in `Array[((String,Double),(String,Double))]` are the same. If so, then you could try the following:

```
val myRDD=Array[((String,Double),(String,Double))]

val strings = myRDD.map(a=>a._1._1)

val values = myRDD.map(a=>(a._1._2,a._2._2))

val rows = strings.zip(values)

val rowsDF=rows.map{case (a,b)=>(a,b._1,b._2)}.toDF
```

For example, consider the following dummy data

```
val myRDD=sc.parallelize(Array((("string1",1.0),("string1",2.0)),(("string2",3.0),("string2",4.0))))

myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, Double), (String, Double))] = ParallelCollectionRDD[33] at parallelize at <console>:27
```

The output will be

```
scala> rowsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: double, _3: double]
scala> rowsDF.collect()
res49: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([string1,1.0,2.0], [string2,3.0,4.0])
```